# Differences between "teenage ages loves" & "teen ages loves"

Tags: word-choice

I am confused about which of the above terms to use in referring to love stories which usually happen for younger people between 13 and 19. Is it normal to use *age* twice in one sentence for both *teenage* and *ages*? Why not *teen ages*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally a native English speaker would use the word "teenager" or say that the person is "in their teens":

> Teenagers love skateboards
>
> People in their teens love my app

When talking about things that happen in one's teens in the general case, you can use a sentence similar to the following:

> Everyone remembers their first teenage romance.

You should be aware though that "teenagers" generally refers to the range 13-18 or 13-19. If you want to refer to a slightly wider range, you can use the term "Young Adult".

Comment: If I have to choose between two above terms in the question which of is a better fit for mentioned reason?

Comment: @user37324: Neither. Both sound wrong. If you're talking about "things that are teenage" in the general case (for example "teenage romances"), you could use "teenage loves" (for example "teenage loves are fleeting"). When referring to people who are between 13-19, you can refer to them as "people in their teens" or "teenagers", but never as "people who are teenage age" or "people who are teen age".

Comment: @Matt thanks for the suggestion but surely I do not write "People who are teenage age" or "People who are teen age" but "people in their teen ages" or "people in their teenage ages" as it was my question.

Comment: @user37324: No. You write "**People who are teenagers**" (or just **teenagers**) or "**People who are in their teens**". "People in their teen ages" and "people in their teenage ages" are both wrong. At a push you could go with "**people in their teenage years**" (although even that sounds forced) - but certainly never "people in their teenage ages".